# How to get One particular tomcat PID while several tomcat instances are running in Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, command-line

I am using linux server where 3 instances of tomcat are running for 3 different applications.
While I'm running following command in the terminal,

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

I'm getting 3 different PIDs.

```
12244     1  0 May27 ?        00:02:08 /opt/shs/zulu13.28.11-ca-jdk13.0.1-linux_x64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/app/shs/wag2/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /app/shs/wag2/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/app/shs/wag2/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/app/shs/wag2/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27 -Dcatalina.home=/app/shs/wag2/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/app/shs/wag2/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

2687     1  2 May27 pts/3        00:01:00 /opt/shs/zulu13.28.11-ca-jdk13.0.1-linux_x64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/app/shs/wag1/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /app/shs/wag1/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/app/shs/wag1/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/app/shs/wag1/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27 -Dcatalina.home=/app/shs/wag1/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/app/shs/wag1/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

29534     2  0 May27 ?        00:05:12 /opt/shs/zulu13.28.11-ca-jdk13.0.1-linux_x64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/app/shs/wag3/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /app/shs/wag3/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/bin/bootstrap.jar:/app/shs/wag3/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/app/shs/wag3/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27 -Dcatalina.home=/app/shs/wag3/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/app/shs/wag3/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Now I'm not able to understand which PID I need to kill for a particular tomcat to restart.

Can you please help me to resolve this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like three tomcat process running on the server. Which tomcat do you want to kill? 
Below is the Pid of each tomcat:

```
/app/shs/wag2/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/  12244 
/app/shs/wag1/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/ 2687 
/app/shs/wag3/tomcat/server1/apache-tomcat-9.0.27 29534
```

Even you can use `jcmd` command to print out the process ID of all the JVM processes.

Comment: okay, so you mean that from the corresponding paths of the tomcats, I need to understand which tomcat PID i need to kill. right?

Comment: Yes.3 different tomcat processes running on the server. Also, you can use  jcmd command to check the main JAVA process.